# calloc returns NULL / ENOMEM for large number of blocks

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, out-of-memory, calloc

For a uni project I'm using [CRFSuite](http://www.chokkan.org/software/crfsuite/).
This software relies heavily on dynamic memory allocation using `calloc`.

When I feed it larger sets of data, the program crashes, and debugging has shown that calloc fails to allocate enough memory.
It returns `NULL` and `errno` is set to `ENOMEM`.

This is the code that fails:

```
int crf1dc_set_num_items(crf1d_context_t* ctx, int T)
{
    const int L = ctx->num_labels;

    ctx->num_items = T;

    if (ctx->cap_items < T) {
        free(ctx->backward_edge);
        free(ctx->mexp_state);
        _aligned_free(ctx->exp_state);
        free(ctx->scale_factor);
        free(ctx->row);
        free(ctx->beta_score);
        free(ctx->alpha_score);

        // The folllowing allocation fails:

        ctx->alpha_score = (floatval_t*)calloc(T * L, sizeof(floatval_t));
        if (ctx->alpha_score == NULL) return CRFSUITEERR_OUTOFMEMORY;

        // [..snipped..]
    }

    // [..snipped..]
}
```

As a concrete example, this fails for T * L = 224608388, i.e.:

```
ctx->alpha_score = (floatval_t*)calloc(224608388, sizeof(floatval_t));
```

And `sizeof(floatval_t)` is 8, according to the debugger.
Yes, that's almost 2 GB of memory, but come on...
It fails, no matter if the code is compiled for 32 or 64 bit.
It also fails for a smaller number of blocks.

It succeeds, however, if I put this as the first thing in main, like so:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    floatval_t* foo = (floatval_t*)calloc(224608388, sizeof(floatval_t));
    if (foo != NULL)
    {
        free(foo);
    }

    // [..actual code snipped..]
}
```

The best way to fix this would probably be to refactor the code, so that it no longer depends on continuous memory, but there's no way I could do that. (Apart from me not being smart enough to understand all the details, the code is not documented at all, there are only cryptic variable names, and the project has a veeery strange way of implementing methods... with underscores and `self` parameters...)

So - is there any way I could get rid of this problem?

My system is a Windows 8.1 Enterprise x64 machine with 8 GB of RAM.
I could also try to run it on a different machine, but I'm skeptical if that would really help... It seems like the problem lies elsewhere...

I'm usually a C# person, not a C/C++ expert at all... (I know the very basics though.)

Thank you!

Comment: Well I'm suspicious of anything that has the magic number `224608388` in it.. Can you try to allocate that much memory at the start of your program, just as a test to see if it works? Try using a tool to detect memory leaks.

Comment: It's not a magic number, it's actually calculated as the product of two positive, signed `int`s.
Putting the allocation as the first thing in `main` succeeds...
But I mean, even if there should be some memory leaks, isn't there some other way to make this work?

Comment: Is that the real code or not?

Comment: If there are memory leaks it could have ran out of memory by the time it reaches it.

Comment: I have edited my question to show the real code. I wanted to keep it simpler. Even if there are memory leaks, shouldn't the OS be able to supply enough memory through paging/swapping? @NeilKirk

Comment: 1G is a ton of memory for an app - especially for windows type where even 64-bit has trouble allocating more than a few gigs.  You are also doing this large allocation after a bunch of frees which makes me think this is a memory fragmentation issue.  Allocating at the beginning of your app before anything else is allocated should prove that out and I will guess would fix this issue.  Having multiple smaller buffers instead of the 1G+ buffer would be better...

Comment: @MichaelDorgan The problem is this is not my code. It's just an app I'm supposed to use for a uni project on machine larning... The program is trained using some data, and that has to be stored somewhere. I've got no idea why this was implemented like this... So allocating at the beginning doesn't help because I don't even know how that memory is filled with data...

Comment: Ah, but allocating early should allow the buffer to be created if fragmentation is the issue.  Once the buffer is yours, it doesn't matter how it filled or not.  We just want you to try this so we can rule out fragmentation as a failure case.

Comment: As I wrote earlier, the allocation succeeds if I just put it as the first thing in `main`... I will update the question to reflect that..